# Powershell password error when creating a new SecretStore vault

Tags: powershell

When attempting to setup a new PS SecretStore vault, I get a prompt to enter a password. It is my understanding that the first time you setup a vault, you need to enter a **new** password in. However, upon typing a new password I get the following message:

```
Set-Secret : A valid password is required to access the Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore vault.
Use the Unlock-SecretStore cmdlet to provide the required password to access the store.
```

What could I potentially be doing wrong as every video and article is able to set this up in a few easy commands. I've also tried 2 different servers to ensure something was not messed up with my local PC.

```
Install-Module Microsoft.Powershell.SecretManagement, Microsoft.Powershell.SecretStore -Scope CurrentUser

Register-SecretVault -Name SecretStoreTest -ModuleName Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore -DefaultVault

get-secretvault

Set-Secret -Name Password1 -Secret "Pa55word"
```

Answer (score -1):

It appears this has to do with not running in administrative mode. I had attempted to run in admin mode on my remote server, but it still failed. When attempting on my local it did indeed work though.